# In Google Analytics can the URL path of the page be used for the "medium" of direct traffic?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, traffic

In Google Analytics I have a lot of `source:direct` `medium:none` in Traffic Sources. Is it possible to have the page's URL in "medium" instead of `none`?

In other words, if someone enters my website directly or via a bookmark, for example `https://www.example.com/abc`, can `/abc` replace `none`?

Comment: I think you can do this although you would have to be *very* careful to avoid overwriting other values for medium - what are you hoping to achieve by making this change?

Comment: Understanding how direct users are reaching my website, be it the Homepage or a particular category they have bookmarked. Maybe I can understand this by checking the Landing Pages report, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to tell if they used a bookmark, typed the page url directly into the browser or got there via some other direct method.

I wouldn't be overwriting/editing the medium. I would either use one of GA's system segments (for direct traffic) and segment that traffic to look at the behaviour of it, or alternatively create a custom report, filtered to only include the medium:none traffic.

Comment: I agree with Bronwyn - segment to direct traffic or filter Landing Pages down via a secondary dimension of Source. And remember that if attribution information is lost for a session, that session will also be marked Direct; not everyone in that group actually used a bookmark or similar.